# com_zoo related items depend on category

Tags: joomla, components

What I really want is to have in my com_zoo app items description page a custom block what is showing the related items to clicked one. So one I found out, that it can be made it manually adding to every specific item the related items. The problem is that is not generated dynamically.
My question would be:is it possible from the actual administration tasks to handle this or it has to be coded. If it has to be code, what is the shortest way to achieve results. should I build a custom element or there is another way to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your related products module may be based on your product tags, for example.

Comment: It's not really clear what you suggest. Could you please explain a bit your workaround.

Comment: Each product of your catalog (Zoo) may contain tags. So you can build your own module based on tag content.  
- A product page is loaded  
- The "related product" module is also loaded with the page  
- The module read product tags  
- Fetch from DB where products have similar tags  
- Show the list in the module position

Comment: and why not a new element what should fetch data's from core? Your method sounds a bit curvy. With your workaround the user would be pushed to set up some tags for each item. In this case I could use the related item element what is already implemented and add all the related items manually

Comment: No, the user don't do anything! When you manage your Zoo products in the backend, YOU define some tags for each of them (see demo here : [link](http://www.yootheme.com/demo/themes/joomla/2012/revista/index.php?option=com_zoo&task=item&item_id=119&category_id=17&Itemid=10)). It's a core feature!

Comment: yeah I saw this. But as i mention I would not like to push the back-end privileged user to select previously some tags to have the related items depends on category displayed just to put the element on the position where he wants to be displayed the related items . Actually a good scenario would be: frontend user clicks on one of the categories item->item details page is getting displayed and in one of the template positions is getting loaded as well all the related items inside from that category.

Comment: I'm also talking about front-end view! I know my english is not good but i feel you don't understand me...